# Surjective, injective and bijection problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a homework problem that is to find the range that allows the function below to be bijective. $$\ f(x) = x^3 -x^2 -x+1  $$ 
 My problem is I don't know how to go about showing this function is either surjective or injectieve. So far we have worked with simple stuff like $\ x+1 $ or $\ x^2 $ I understand that injective functions are found like this:

$$ \begin{align} 
& f(x) = x^3\\ 
& f(a) = f(b)\\ 
& a^3 = b^3\\ 
& a = b\\
\end{align}$$

and for surjective functions I need  $\ b = f(a) $ so,

$$ \begin{align}
f(a) = b\\
a^3 = b\\
a=\sqrt[3]{b}
\end{align}$$

I am quite confident about finding the domain, but have no idea how to tackle this function.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Is your function $f(x)=x^3$ or $f(x) = x^2-x+1$? Right now, you say $f(x)=x^3=x^2-x+1$ which doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed and edited the formula. should be a - where the second = is

Comment: @5xum I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is a third degree polynomial, you will have a harder time proving injectivity and surjectivity, but it will be possible. I will first only give you one hint:

Try to plot the function as accurately as possible. Once you have plotted it, you can usually guess if the function is surjective and if it is injective. Once you guess the right answer, it is easier to prove it (since you are not proving the "wrong" answer.

To plot the function, you should find its zeros and the zeros of the derivative, which should not be hard.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.

Comment: After graphing the fuction, it looks like I can use the first derivative and the ranges that will work will match the signs.

Comment: @travis OK, but does that mean the function is injective or surjective? And leads yet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to run to the store. Anyway: I got it down to  $\ x^2(x-1)-(x-1) = (x-1)(x^2-1) = (x-1)(x-1)(x+1) $ so my zeros are x={-1,1}; Then for the derivative I got $\ 3x^2-2x-1 = (3x+1)(x-1)$ so the zeros there are x={-1/3,1}

Comment: That is correctly done. Using this data, you can plot your function, then try to figure out if it is surjective and injective. Once you figure that out, it will be simple to prove it. For example, you can already tell if it is injective or not. (It is injective if $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x=y$ and it is not injective if there exists such a pair $x\neq y$ that $f(x) = f(y)$

Comment: I think I have it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: basically, to tackle this task, you need both to:

- Find out the different growth domains of the functions by finding our the zeros of $f'(x)$, noted $x_i$
- Then solve the equations $f(x)=f(x_i)$, which will be giving $x_j$ and $x_i$ (obviously)

You just have to study all the domains $]-\infty;x_1], [x_1;x_2]...$ and find where $f(x)$ is injective and subjective...

You don't need the zeroes of $f(x)$ by the way.

Answer (score -1):

A function that is continuous and monotonous increasing or decreasing is injective.
Every polynomial function is continuous everywhere.

In order to be surjective, just watch out that the codomain of $f$ is equal to its range. As an example, assume that $f(x)$ has domain $D$ and range $R \neq \mathbb{R}$. In that case, $f:D \rightarrow R$ is surjective, but $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not.

Comment: $f:D\to \mathbb R$ can be surjective if $R=\mathbb R$. Also, you have given no hint to the user how to prove injectivity.

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand about "continuous and monotonous increasing or decreasing."